# why underline is removed by changing the style of font?

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-styling

I'm a beginner in android ,so please do excuse me if my question is foolish.Basically I'm trying to make a text editor so after a lot of try I'm able to add the `bold`,`italic`,`bold-italic` styles to text without any problem. But now when I'm trying to add `underline` to text `underline` is added without any error but when I'm changing the style for ex-`bold` to `bold-italic` then the underline is removed from last underlined charecters[[image]][See here `underline` is there below `bold`text]

[[image]][Now `underline` is shifted to next charecters by removing last `underline`]

My Code:

```
public class TextArea extends EditText {

public static final int TYPEFACE_NORMAL = 0;
public static final int TYPEFACE_BOLD = 1;
public static final int TYPEFACE_ITALICS = 2;
public static final int TYPEFACE_BOLD_ITALICS = 3;
public static final boolean underline=false;

private int currentTypeface;
private int lastCursorPosition;
private int tId;


public TextArea(Context context) {
    super(context);
    lastCursorPosition = this.getSelectionStart();
}

public TextArea(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


public int gettId() {
    return tId;
}

public void settId(int tId) {
    this.tId = tId;
}

public void changeTypeface(int tfId) {
    currentTypeface = tfId;
    lastCursorPosition = this.getSelectionStart();
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    Spannable str = this.getText();
    StyleSpan ss;UnderlineSpan tt = new UnderlineSpan();
    int endLength = text.toString().length();

    switch(currentTypeface) {
        case TYPEFACE_NORMAL:
            ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
            break;
        case TYPEFACE_BOLD:
            ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
            break;
        case TYPEFACE_ITALICS:
            ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
            break;
        case TYPEFACE_BOLD_ITALICS:
            ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            break;
        default:
            ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
    if(underline){
    str.setSpan(ss, lastCursorPosition, endLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    str.setSpan(tt, lastCursorPosition, endLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}   
    else{
 str.setSpan(ss, lastCursorPosition, endLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
}
}
```

From MainActivity.java

```
bold=findViewById(R.id.bold);
italic=findViewById(R.id.italic);
boldItalic=findViewById(R.id.boldItalic);
editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
normal=findViewById(R.id.normal);
underline=findViewById(R.id.underline);
typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_NORMAL;
editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_NORMAL;
     editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
 }
});
  bold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
              typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_BOLD;
     editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
    }
  });
 italic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
              typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_ITALICS;
     editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
 }
 });
  boldItalic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
              typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_BOLD_ITALICS;

     editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);

             }}
 }
 });

  underline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if(under_it) {
         under_it = false;
         TextArea.underline=false;
         editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
         underline.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#001919"));
     }
     else {
         under_it = true;
         TextArea.underline=true;
         editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
         underline.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fc0505"));

             }}
     }
          }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok buddy here is your solution.

Check it and let me know if this works ...

TextArea.java

```
public class TextArea extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    public static final int TYPEFACE_NORMAL = 0;
    public static final int TYPEFACE_BOLD = 1;
    public static final int TYPEFACE_ITALICS = 2;
    public static final int TYPEFACE_BOLD_ITALICS = 3;
    public static final int TYPEFACE_UNDERLINE = 4;
    public static boolean underline = false;

    private int currentTypeface;
    private int lastCursorPosition;
    private int tId;


    public TextArea(Context context) {
        super(context);
        lastCursorPosition = this.getSelectionStart();
    }

    public TextArea(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public int gettId() {
        return tId;
    }

    public void settId(int tId) {
        this.tId = tId;
    }

    public void changeTypeface(int tfId) {
        currentTypeface = tfId;
        lastCursorPosition = this.getSelectionStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        Spannable str = this.getText();
        StyleSpan ss;
        UnderlineSpan tt = new UnderlineSpan();
        int endLength = text.toString().length();
        underline = false;

        Log.d("onTextChanged ", text.toString());

        switch (currentTypeface) {
            case TYPEFACE_NORMAL:
                ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
                break;
            case TYPEFACE_BOLD:
                ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
                break;
            case TYPEFACE_ITALICS:
                ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
                break;
            case TYPEFACE_UNDERLINE:
                underline = true;
                ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
                tt = new UnderlineSpan();
                break;
            case TYPEFACE_BOLD_ITALICS:
                ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                break;
            default:
                ss = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
        if (underline) {
//            str.setSpan(ss, lastCursorPosition, endLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            str.setSpan(tt, lastCursorPosition, endLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else {
            // Runtime Error Fix!
            if (endLength > lastCursorPosition)
                str.setSpan(ss, lastCursorPosition, endLength, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity

```
    bold = findViewById(R.id.bold);
    italic = findViewById(R.id.italic);
    boldItalic = findViewById(R.id.boldItalic);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    normal = findViewById(R.id.normal);
    underline = findViewById(R.id.underline);
    typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_NORMAL;
    editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);

    normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_NORMAL;
            editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
        }
    });


    bold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_BOLD;
            editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
        }
    });

    italic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_ITALICS;
            editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);
        }
    });

    boldItalic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_BOLD_ITALICS;
            editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);

        }
    });


    underline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            typefaceStyle = TextArea.TYPEFACE_UNDERLINE;
                editText.changeTypeface(typefaceStyle);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir it solved my issue . But could you please elaborate what was the problem?