# how to make text of text underlined using HTML tags

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm a beginner in android so please do excuse me if my question is foolish.I wonder how can i make text of edit text underlined by using `html` tags.
For example with a TextView  I can do like `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Hi</u>"))` but how can I use this with `EditText`?

Although I can do like `editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Hi</u>"))` but how can I underline the text which is being typed by the user

Comment: Since editText is a subclass of textView then does this work? try it `editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Hi</u>"))`

Comment: I can do that but how to do at runtime like the text should be underline when I type anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `TextWatcher` and `SpannableString`

```
    et_user_email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            et_user_email.removeTextChangedListener(this);

            SpannableString content = new SpannableString(s);
            content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, s.length(), 0);

            et_user_email.setText(content);
            et_user_email.setSelection(s.length());

            et_user_email.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
    });
```

Result -

[image: edittext spannable]

Comment: It's working amzingly but could you help me to solve a similar problem like[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385158/why-underline-is-removed-by-changing-the-style-of-font]

Answer (score 2):

`Html.fromHtml(mString)` method is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#pubmethods). Avoid using it, use `Spannable` instead,

```
String mText="Hi";
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(mText);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, udata.length(), 0);
mView.setText(content); //set it to EditText or TextView
```

here's a example to set it while typing,

```
 et_my_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            stringBeforeChange = s.toString(); //temp variable
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!et_my_text.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(stringBeforeChange)) { //this prevents infinite loop
                SpannableString content = new SpannableString(s.toString());
                content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, s.toString().length(), 0);
                et_my_text.setText(content);
                et_my_text.setSelection(et_my_text.getText().length()); //this keeps cursor at the end of editText
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sir, it's working like a charm but could you please tell me how to remove underline from the underlined text because by removeSpan method

Comment: And [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385158/why-underline-is-removed-by-changing-the-style-of-font) this error is all bothering by using span

Comment: just use `et_my_text.setText(et_my_text.getText().toString());` to remove the formatting in EditText, Also you need to apply all the formatting again everytime you do `setText`, in the link the code applies bold but doesn't apply underline again that is why the underline gets removed

Comment: but in that link's question he's applying underline after style like bold italic span by checking boolean status

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText passwordEditText;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Initializing views */
        passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


        /* Set Text Watcher listener */
        passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(passwordWatcher);
    }

    private final TextWatcher passwordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String incomingText = passwordEditText.getText();
            passwordEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>"+incomingText+"</u>"));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else{
                textView.setText("You have entered : " + passwordEditText.getText());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can change text as user types in:

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(tw);

            String text = editText.getText().toString(); 
            editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>" + text + "</u>");

            editText.addTextChangedListener(tw);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    };

editText.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: this will go in infinite loop as the afterTextChanged will get called everytime you set new text

Comment: @shantanu infinite loop issue fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be possible to do this using an editext, I'd suggest that you use a [RichEdititor](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) as the native `EditText` starts to get slow if you try to load a large HTML. Wasabeef has a great [library](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) for it

[image]

```
RichEditor editor = (RichEditor) findViewById(R.id.editor);

        findViewById(R.id.action_underline).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEditor.setUnderline();
            }
        });
```

You can also add other things like `subscript`,`superscript`,`strikethrough` e.t.c

Comment: Thanks a lot sir/ma'm it helped me to avoid the boilerplate codes for simple tasks

Comment: @NizaSilwale But sir, now I'm having a problem how can i get text from the editor view because getText() method is not working

Comment: Use `getHtml()`

Comment: Sir,I'm sorry to trouble you again . Could you please tell is there any way to limit the number of lines in richEdit

Comment: You can limit the number of lines by limiting the number of `<br/>` characters as they are the ones that create new lines in HTML

Comment: could you please give an example with respect to this context

Answer (score 0):

A very convenient way to deal with text changes is to use "com.jakewharton.rxbinding.widget"

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText).map(text -> Html.fromHtml("<u>" + text + "</u>")).subscribe();
```

(I haven't tested the code but it should work like that)

You include it in your dependencies like this:

```
implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:${rxBindingsVersion}"
```